# error al instalar mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, datatables

estoy tratando de instalar mysqlclient para django, y me da el siguiente error:

> Failed to build mysqlclient
> Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
> Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Running setup.py install for mysqlclient did not run >successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [29 lines of output]
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win32-3.10
> creating build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb
> copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb
> creating build\lib.win32-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32->3.10\MySQLdb\constants
> running build_ext
> building 'MySQLdb.*mysql' extension
> creating build\temp.win32-3.10
> creating build\temp.win32-3.10\Release
> creating build\temp.win32-3.10\Release\MySQLdb
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual >Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl>.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=>(2,1,0,'final',0) -D__version*_=2.1.0 -IC:\Program >Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mariadb -IC:\Program >Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include ->IC:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\e-commerce-pj\e_commerce-env\include ->IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310->32\include ->IC:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-?>32\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual >Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include ->IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um ->IC:\Program >Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt ->IC:\Program >Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared ->IC:\Program >Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um ->IC:\Program >Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt ->IC:\Program >Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt >/TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32->3.10\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
> _mysql.c
> MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el >archivo incluir: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual >Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX8
> 6\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

y no entiendo que pasa.
este es el paquete:

```
    Package    Version
    ---------- -------
    asgiref    3.5.2
    Django     4.0.4
    pip        22.1.1
    setuptools 58.1.0
    sqlparse   0.4.2
    tzdata     2022.1
    wheel      0.37.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionar.
en la version inglesa de stackoverflow está la solucion.

Descargué y luego intalé el conector de MySQL desde la pagina oficial, marcó un error diferente que hablaba de MariaDB y procedí a descargar e intalar el conector de MariaDB